# solving the PDE $u_{xx}-u_{xy}- 2u_{yy} = 0$ with initial conditions $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$, $u_y(x,0) = \psi(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I am trying to solve this PDE and not sure if I'm on the right track. I first found (using a change of variables) the general solution in the form $$u(x,y)=f(x-y)+g(x+\frac{y}{2})$$

Then, the initial conditions give me the following equations:
$$u(x,0) = f(x) + g(x) =\phi(x) \tag{1}$$
$$u_y(x,0) = - f'(x) +\frac{1}{2}g'(x) =\psi(x) \tag{2}$$

From there I solved the system of equations of (1) and (2) to get
$$\frac{3}{2} g'(x)=\phi'(x) +\psi(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow g'(x) = \frac{2}{3}(\phi'(x)+\psi(x))$$

Then from (1):
$$ f'(x) = \phi'(x)-g'(x) =\frac{1}{3}\phi'(x) +\psi(x)$$

Integrating both sides, I got
$$\int f' dx= f(x) = \frac{1}{3}\phi(x)+\int_{0}^x \psi(s) ds $$
$$\Rightarrow g(x) = \phi(x)-f(x) = \frac{2}{3}\phi(x) -\int_{0}^x \psi(s) ds$$
So then,

$$u(x,y) = f(x-y)+g(x+\frac{y}{2}) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{3}\phi(x-y)+\frac{2}{3}\phi(x+\frac{y}{2})+\int_0^{x-y}\psi(s)ds-\int_0^{x+\frac{y}{2}}\psi(s)ds$$

$$ =  \frac{1}{3}\phi(x-y)+\frac{2}{3}\phi(x+\frac{y}{2})-\int_{x-y}^{x+\frac{y}{2}} \psi(s)ds $$

Im not sure if this is the right approach--this is my first time solving a problem of this type, so I was just following along with the derivation of the general solution of the wave equation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your approach is correct, but you made a mistake in the equation following "Then from (1)" that propagated to the final answer. The corrected equation is $$f'(x) = \phi'(x)-g'(x) =\frac{1}{3}\phi'(x) -\frac{2}{3}\psi(x).$$